# Sous Vide Brisket Interrupted, is that safe?

Tags: food-safety, temperature, brisket

First of all, sorry for my bad english, I'm a foreign.

I'm new at sous vide world, and have a doubt, and I'm wondering if someone more experienced can help me.

For days I was looking for the ingredients to make this recipe: https://www.chefsteps.com/activities/smokerless-smoked-brisket

I did all like the recipe says, including using the Prague Powder nº 1 (very difficult to buy in Brazil since the sell was restricted by law).

**The Problem:**

After the meat rested for 3 hours with Prague Powder, was a little late, about 12:00 am, than at 12:30 am I put pre-heated water over 50ºC (122ºF) on the container, and also the meat, programed to cook at 68ºC (154,4ºF), timed for 24 hours. About 01:00 AM, the water reached the target temperature and cooked ok until about 9:00 am, when power was out and obviously turned off the equipment.

I wasn't at home and just figured out when was already 06:00 pm and the water was at 35ºC (95ºF) when immediately I started to heat the water again, with take about one hour to reach 68ºC (154,4ºF), after reached the temperature I let it cook for more 16:30.

**Relevant Facts:**

- I tested, in same container, with same water volume that was cooked the meat, how long it takes to drop the temperature to the critical 54,4°C (130ºF), and the answer is at least 55 minutes;
- Based on that test I think the meat keeped in critical temperature for about 8 hours;
- I used well-prepared vacuum packaging, which left almost no air inside.
  The meat has about 70 mm thickness.

**Questions:**

- The first cook (8 hours at 68ºC (154,4ºF)) was enough to pasteurize the meat?
- Prague Powder can help to prevent pathogens?
- Is it safe to eat this meat?
- What can I expect with the interruption of cooking in terms of loss?

I appreciate if someone with more experience than me can help me.

Thx.

Comment: Hi Leonardo, your side factors like "did the first cook pasteurize the meat" are irrelevant to food safety. Once you leave cooked food in the danger zone, the two hour rule applies, without exception. See the duplicate question for details.